# draw points based on the number of rows in database table in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

i'm trying to draw points on my canvas. the number of points that should be drawn on my canvas will be based on the number of rows on my database table which is named as sample. my problem is i don't get any output

```
function draw()
        {
          canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
          ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
          ctx.fillStyle = "black";

          <?php
          $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "","login");
          if ($conn -> connect_error) {
            die($conn -> connect_error);
          }

          $query = "SELECT COUNT(1) FROM sample";
          $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

          ?>

          var val = "<?php echo $result ?>";
          alert(val);

          for(var i = 0; i < val; i++)
          {
            var x = Math.random()*500;
            var y = Math.random()*300;
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(x , y, 2, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.closePath();

          }
```

i have tried placing alert() to see if my query has been executed but still i don't get any output

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this

```
var val = "<?php echo $result ?>";
```

the whole thing will be interpreted as a simple string, not as php. However you can echo a line of javascript from your php code block above that like so :

```
<?php
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "","login");
if ($conn -> connect_error) {
    die($conn -> connect_error);
}

$query = "SELECT COUNT(1) FROM sample";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

$json = json_encode($result); // converts object to a json string, similar to Javascript's JSON.stringify method
echo "var val = JSON.parse(".$json.");";
?>

alert(val); //this should work!
```

Comment: The issue might be with your connection or your query. Can you inspect the code, and see what php echo'd out above your alert?